# Getting "Specified cast is not valid." error in MS VS 2013

Tags: c#, sql-server

Hi I am creating a webservice with MSSQL, MS VS 2013, C# and everything was going well until this point

```
List<Company_Invoices> customers = new List<Company_Invoices>();
    var json = "";
    var result = dc.ExecuteQuery<Company_Invoices>(@"SELECT top 10 
      sih.[No_],
      sih.[External Document No_], 
      sih.[Due Date], 
      sih.[Order Date], 
      sih.[Posting Date],
      sih.[Shipment Date], 
      cus.[Id] as 'Sell To Customer Id',
      cust.[Id] as 'Bill To Customer Id', 
      sih.[Currency Code], 
      sih.[Salesperson Code],
      sih.[Location Code], 
      cle.[Open], 
      cle.[Sales (LCY)], 
      (SELECT SUM([Amount (LCY)]) AS Expr1 
          FROM dbo.[Company$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry] AS d 
          WHERE  ([Cust_ Ledger Entry No_] = cle.[Entry No_])
             AND ([Entry Type] = 1) AND ([Posting Date] = cle.[Posting Date]))  
          as 'Sum Amount LCY',
      (SELECT SUM([Amount (LCY)]) AS Expr1 
          FROM dbo.[Company$Detailed Cust_ Ledg_ Entry] AS dcle 
          WHERE ([Cust_ Ledger Entry No_] = cle.[Entry No_])) as 'Sum Amount LCY2' 
      FROM dbo.[Company$Sales Invoice Header] AS sih 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Company$Cust_ Ledger Entry] AS cle 
          ON cle.[Document No_] = sih.No_ 
          AND cle.[Document Type] = 2 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Company$Customer] AS cus 
          ON sih.[Sell-to Customer No_] = cus.[No_] 
      LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.[Company$Customer] AS cust 
          ON sih.[Bill-to Customer No_] = cust.[No_]");

    customers = result.ToList<Company_Invoices>();
    json = jss.Serialize(customers);
    return json;
```

The query when run as a simple SQL query executes fine but in the code the result is

```
{"Specified cast is not valid."}
```

What is wrong? Asking because I did several similar queries and they worked fine but this one is not very different.

Comment: What is `Company_Invoices`? And where exactly did you get the error?

Comment: `Company_Invoices` is a data class generated in the `.dbml` file.

Comment: Can you show its code? Sure all fields match? And their data types too?

Comment: how could i show you?

Comment: I also encourage You to care about indents - it's a huge increase of readability. Maybe I know the solution but I'm not going to read this query as it hurts to read it.

Comment: http://dpaste.com/2VA28T4  the generated classes, readable query and query result sample

Comment: Are you sure the types of the query's columns match the types of the properties in your class? Note that a column may contain just digits and still be a varchar, so the property must be a string, not an int.

Comment: You were right `cle.[Open]` was TinyInt so I needed to change the DataClass type for it to `System.Byte`

Comment: is your problem solved by changing the data type of `cle.[open]` ?

Comment: Yes! That solved my problem! Thank You all for helping